# macOS app works fine in Mojave but crashes in Catalina Beta version

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-mojave, core-foundation, macos-catalina

I was trying to test app that works fine on Mojave but keeps crashing on Catalina. I am providing the crash details below for any help.What could be the reason for it to not work on Catalina?
I was trying to test app that works fine on Mojave but keeps crashing on Catalina. I am providing the crash details below for any help.What could be the reason for it to not work on Catalina?

```
Process:               SSWatcher [9887]
Path:                  /Library/Application Support/safe/MacOS/SSWatcher
Identifier:            com.safe.sswatcher
Version:               1.0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           SSWatcher [9887]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-09-18 16:02:08.870 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15 (19A558d)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        75520E05-90C3-B100-E7E3-3AE1B6910181

Sleep/Wake UUID:       551DFEAF-E97E-42BB-9610-A525913A821B

Time Awake Since Boot: 6900 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff396d8033 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f6e6bd4 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3979adda _CFThrowFormattedException + 202
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39798dc0 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:].cold.2 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39618811 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 1255
5   SSWatcher                           0x000000010d1a5314 -[DNCurrentWindow SetFrontMostWindow] + 1540
6   SSWatcher                           0x000000010d1a3e15 _Z29InstallSSWatcherEventHandlersv + 85
7   SSWatcher                           0x000000010d1a9111 -[DNMainController awakeFromNib] + 545
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3968d735 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 231
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff36855e8c -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1485
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff36853eaf loadNib + 401
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff3685345e +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 693
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff368530b4 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff36852e8d +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 446
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff368490b6 NSApplicationMain + 505
15  SSWatcher                           0x000000010d1a37e2 main + 34
16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff70a452a5 start + 1
17  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff70b942aa __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70c51707 pthread_kill + 384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff70b1ca08 abort + 120
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6dbe8bc8 abort_message + 231
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6dbe8d7c demangling_terminate_handler() + 262
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6f6e8aaa _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6dbf5da7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6dbf5b55 __cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 27
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff6dbe734f __cxa_throw + 113
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff6f6e6d02 objc_exception_throw + 350
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3979adda _CFThrowFormattedException + 202
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff39798dc0 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:].cold.1 + 35
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff39618811 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 1255
13  com.esafe.sswatcher             0x000000010d1a5314 -[DNCurrentWindow SetFrontMostWindow] + 1540
14  com.esafe.sswatcher             0x000000010d1a3e15 InstallSSWatcherEventHandlers() + 85
15  com.esafe.sswatcher             0x000000010d1a9111 -[DNMainController awakeFromNib] + 545
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3968d735 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 231
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff36855e8c -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1485
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff36853eaf loadNib + 401
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3685345e +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 693
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff368530b4 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff36852e8d +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 446
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff368490b6 NSApplicationMain + 505
23  com.esafe.sswatcher             0x000000010d1a37e2 main + 34
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff70a452a5 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70c4e5b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70c4e5b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70c4e5b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70c4e5b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000118023d40  rcx: 0x00007ffee2a5b8f8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee2a5b920  rsp: 0x00007ffee2a5b8f8
   r8: 0x00007ffee2a5b7c0   r9: 0x00007ffee2a5b990  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff70b942aa  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00007fff9d6a7628

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Hope the details are enough

Comment: Have you run your app under the debugger? That should tell you exactly which line of `SetFrontMostWindow` is calling `insertObject:atIndex:` passing it `nil`, and from there you can work backwards to the source of the `nil` and determine what Catalina is doing differently to Mojave.

Comment: Note that this exception can also be thrown if the index is out of range.